# How to select the top and low 10% values of a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, tidyverse

**Question updated:**

I have the `DF` `data.frame` that has `two variables`. I would like to have the `high 10%` and `low 10%` of `DF` data, saved in a different `data.frame` Below is my sample data set with a desired output. Any comments/suggestions are appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF <- data.frame(D1 = 1:30, D2 = 36:65)
```

**Desired output:**

```
 DF_High  <- data.frame(D1 = c(30,29,28), D2 = c(65,64,63))
 DF_Low  <- data.frame(D1 = c(1,2,3), D2 = c(36,37,38))
```

Comment: You have two variables, which variable you want to use to extract top rows? Or what you want is `head(DF,0.10*(nrow(DF)))` and `tail(DF,0.10*(nrow(DF)))`?

Comment: I tried the `head(DF,0.10*(nrow(DF)))`, it doesn't sort both variables simultaneously. i am looking to `sort` both `D1` and `D2` in `Descending` for `10% High` and then `ascending` for `10% Low`.

Comment: I have added a code for possible solution to your issue. If I understand correctly you want to order twice and then extract.

Comment: I think your question is unclear and bit confusing. Would you be able to create a short example with 10/20 rows and show expected output for it? That would help immensely.

Comment: @RonakShah thanks and sorry for the confusion. See the edits- hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `across` to get top 10% of values from each column.

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 0.1 * nrow(DF)
Dfhigh <- DF %>%summarise(across(.fns = ~sort(.x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:n]))
Dflow <- DF %>%summarise(across(.fns = ~sort(.x)[1:n]))
```

---

In base R, we can do :

```
Dfhigh <- sapply(DF, function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:n])
Dflow <- sapply(DF, function(x) sort(x)[1:n])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, based on comments you want to order twice and then extract. Here the code using your data `DF`:

```
#Code for high
DF2 <- DF[order(-DF$D1,-DF$D2),]
#Code for low
DF3 <- DF[order(DF$D1,DF$D2),]
#Extract
DFHigh <- head(DF2,0.10*nrow(DF2))
DFLow <- head(DF3,0.10*nrow(DF3))
```

**Update:** Here a solution reshaping data:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
#Data
DF <- data.frame(D1 = runif(500,1,50), D2 = runif(100, 5,60))
#Code
Melted <- DF %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  arrange(name,desc(value)) %>% group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value)
#Choose high
dfhigh <- head(Melted,0.10*nrow(Melted))
dflow <- tail(Melted,0.10*nrow(Melted))
```

Comment: Thanks @Duck, when i use `DF2 <- DF[order(-DF$D1,-DF$D2),]` I thought the `data.frame (DF)` would be sorted in descending (higher to lower) order, however, seems like only `column 1 (D1)` is sorted. here is quick way that i used to check  `head(DF,5)`

Comment: @Hydro I have added an update. Please check, I think you want to sort each variable and then extract top 10% and low 10%. Check last code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. i updated the question with a desired output- have a look.